# Why is the annihilator of a smooth distribution smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\Delta$ be a smooth regular distribution on a manifold $M$. This means that for all $p\in M$, $\Delta(p)$ is a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $T_{p}M$ and moreover around any $p\in M$ we find an open neighborhood $U$ and linearly independent vector fields $X_{1},\ldots,X_{k}$ on $U$ such that for all $q\in U$:
$$\text{span}\{X_{1}(q),\ldots,X_{k}(q)\}=\Delta(q)$$

We now consider $\Delta^{0}$, the annihilator of $\Delta$. At each point $p\in M$ it is defined as
$$\Delta^{0}(p)=\{\alpha\in (T_{p}M)^{*}:\ \alpha(w)=0\ \forall w\in\Delta(p)\}.$$

How can I see that $\Delta^{0}$ is a smooth codistribution? To prove this, I guess we have to take $\alpha\in\Delta^{0}(p)$ and extend it locally to a one form on $M$ that annihilates the vector fields $X_{1},\ldots,X_{k}$.

Comment: Locally, you might extend $X_1,\dots,X_k$ to a smoothly varying basis $X_1,\dots,X_k,X_{k+1},\dots,X_n$ for the tangent bundle of $M$ and let $\omega^1,\dots,\omega^n$ be the dual basis for the cotangent bundle. Then $\Delta^0$ has (on this open set) the basis $\omega^{k+1},\dots,\omega^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Outline only:) one option is to introduce a smooth Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$, create (locally) a smooth basis $n_i$of the normal bundle to the distribution (using Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization, which allows you to do this smoothly) and write a basis of the annihilator using the Riesz representation theorem, i.e.
$$\alpha_i(v):= g(n_i, v)$$